# Okta login request expiration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, okta

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses Okta for authentication, implemented using Authorization code flow method. For authentication, when my application redirects to Okta Sign-In page, if I delay logging in by few minutes, I get a 400 error page with the description  "Request expired, please start over and try again."

Does anyone know how to increase the request expiration?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Okta haven't improved in the last 3 years.
I have the same issue now and the Okta support case didn't solve the problem. They provide a solution but it is not suitable for us because we can not add the embedded Sign-In Widget to the commercial sofware.
https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/Request-expired-please-start-over-and-try-again?language=en_US

As long as the login button click is delayed for a few minutes, it will show a 400 error which is very confusing for end user.